Apache Tomcat basada en ARP rendimiento optimo
iNFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path... haber si alguien puede ayudarme con este error al iniciar tomcat 6 y al abrir la consola me sale este error.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
